# SQL Server returns Conversion failed error when using OPENJSON and JOIN

Tags: arrays, json, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to create a SQL Server stored procedure with a JSON input parameter.

I followed this documentation by Microsoft:

- [OPENJSON (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#examples) (Please see Example 1)
- [Passing arrays to T-SQL procedures as JSON](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server/passing-arrays-to-t-sql-procedures-as-json/ba-p/384438)

I've created the below Stored Procedure where the input parameter `@JsonIds` has to be a JSON integer array stored inside a `NVARCHAR` data type variable.

This is the sample code, very similar to what showed on the above linked docs:

```sql
CREATE OR ALTER PROCEDURE [MySP]
    @JsonIds NVARCHAR(200)  -- JSON Array of Ids.
AS
BEGIN

    IF (ISNULL(@JsonIds, 0) = 0 OR ISJSON(@JsonIds) = 0)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Invalid JSON parameter.', 16, 1)
        RETURN
    END

    SELECT T.*
    FROM MyTable T
    INNER JOIN OPENJSON(@JsonIds) AS Ids ON T.Id = Ids.value;
END
```

But when I execute the stored procedure like this:

```
EXEC [MySP] @JsonIds=N'[1,4]';
```

This is the result:

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure MySP, Line 21 [Batch Start Line 0]
> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '[1,4]' to data type int.

I don't understand why it is giving me the conversion error.

**Environment**:

- SQL Server 2017 v14.0.3356.20
- SSMS v18.9.1

Comment: Shouldn't json start and end with curly brackets? `{ & }` - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/openjson-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @MichaelZ. I had the same doubt and so I tried, but no, nothing changed. Anyway, on the linked docs, the JSON array was written without the curly brackets, like I did.

Comment: Maybe not, but is you Json proper for this SQL function? I feel like your Json is missing something but since I'm not familiar with `OPENJSON` I'm just guessing.

Comment: ok I guess I'm wrong because this works - `SELECT * FROM OPENJSON(N'[4,1]')`

Comment: but I see the issue, `value` is being returned as `nvarchar`

Comment: @MichaelZ. My code is very, very close to the docs samples. So my JSON is just an integer array like the one in the code samples. The `Id` column of `MyTable` is also `INT` data type.

Comment: An array is valid json.

Comment: That specific error will be raised if you call the proc like: EXEC [MySP] @JsonIds=N'[[1,4]]';

Comment: @lptr I'm not calling the stored procedure that way with double squared brackets. Anyway, I tried and I get back the same error.

Comment: @lptr that is a very good observation. But where are the extra brackets coming from? Make an answer for it. I'll delete my answer because technically it should convert on the fly even though it's better to convert ahead of time IMO.

Comment: .. there it is, the conversion error…. IF (ISNULL(@JsonIds, 0) = 0

Comment: @MichaelZ., @lptr It was my mistake! The error wasn't on the `JOIN` code, but on the `IF` statement above, that was not previously shown in my question's code sample for brevity... The problem was related to the `ISNULL(@JsonIds, 0) = 0` check.

Comment: If you are "in the habit" of writing that, get out of it -- `@x IS NULL OR @x = 0` (where applicable, in this case the `@x = 0` would of course need to be omitted) typically performs better than `ISNULL(@x, 0) = 0`, as the former is amenable to index lookups and the latter is not. Of course in this case we're dealing with scalars do it doesn't matter, but generally speaking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to stick with your method of testing you will need to surround the 0 with quotes as it cant check if the nvarchar json string is equal to an int.

```sql
IF (ISNULL(N'[1,4]', '0') = '0' OR ISJSON(N'[1,4]') = 0)
```